# Livewire validation with custom rule and additional parameters

Tags: laravel, forms, validation, laravel-livewire

I have a Form where a `timeslot` (the validating field) might be valid for `employee A` (another field in the component), but not for `employee B`.

I have a custom validation Rule `TimeSlotEmployee` that checks for the correctness of the combination `(employee, timeslot)` through `request('employee_id')` and the `$value` parameter of the `passes` function, and so far it works fine.

I'm now moving this form into a Livewire component, but I'm facing difficulties because in the POST request that is triggered by the update of the `timeslot` field there is no `employee_id`, only the new `timeslot` value.

How can I solve this problem? Am I tackling it from the wrong angle?

**Update**

This is the `rules` function inside the `TimeSlotRequest`:

```
public function rules()
{
  return [
    'employee_id' => ['required', 'numeric'],
    'timeslot' => ['required', new TimeSlotEmployeeRule()],
  ];
}
```

In the `TimeSlotEmployeeRule`, this is the `passes` function:

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $timesloteValue = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i', $value);
    $employee = Employee::find(request('employee_id'));

    // perform checks: this part works, but requires the employee instance

   return true;
}
```

In the Livewire component, I use the standard `updated` method:

```
public function updated($propertyName)
{
    $this->validateOnly($propertyName);
}
```

Comment: It would greatly help to see your actual code, otherwise we'll just be guessing.

Comment: I updated my question with code snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the request in Livewire needs to rehydrate the component, you can never fully depend on the `request()` helper, particularly in subrequests - as the data being passed is Livewire's data.

You should pass the value as a parameter to the rule instead, like so,

```php
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class TimeSlotEmployeeRule implements Rule
{
    public int $employee_id;

    public function __construct($employee_id)
    {
        $this->employee_id = $employee_id;
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $timesloteValue = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i', $value);
        $employee = Employee::find($this->employee_id);

        // perform checks: this part works, but requires the employee instance

       return true;
    }
}
```

Then in the rules, you pass in the ID,

```php
public function rules()
{
  return [
    'employee_id' => ['required', 'numeric'],
    'timeslot' => ['required', new TimeSlotEmployeeRule($this->employee_id)],
  ];
}
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was thinking to do. Thanks!

Comment: Great answer - was also digging around on how to do similar. Thanks :-)

Comment: Except that 

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule
```
has been deprecated.

I guess there's a "New" improved way of handling this type of functionality... Not getting any lightning bolts of clarity here though :/