# Livewire validation with custom rule doesn't show error

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, flatpickr

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76593881/1785967) and [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76604039/1785967), I managed to create the flatpickr element and to send data to the backend. The problem is that, although in the `Rule` that validates the datetime the `passes` method returns `false`, the validation error is not shown in the form.

For sake of easy-reading, this is the blade portion for the datepicker:

```
<div class="mb-3" wire:ignore>
    <label for="pickeddatetime" class="form-label">Date and time</label>
    <input id="pickeddatetime" class="form-control @error('pickeddatetime') is-invalid @enderror"
           type="datetime-local" name="pickeddatetime" placeholder="Pick a date and time"
           value="{{ old('pickeddatetime') }}" wire:model.debounce.500ms="pickeddatetime">
    @error('pickeddatetime')
    <p class="invalid-feedback">{{ $errors->first('pickeddatetime') }}</p>
    @enderror
</div>
```

I believe it is due to the `wire:ignore` directive (used to make flatpickr work with Livewire) preventing any change in the DOM but, again, I'm still learning and thus be completely wrong.

## Update

I moved `wire:ignore` inside the `input` field, and that's the only change I made in the Blade file. There are no other `wire:ignore` in there, and the `@livewireScripts` is in the layout file (I can see the scripts in the DOM of the Livewire component).

The validation goes as follows: when the datetime is selected, the `updatedPickeddatetime` is called (and indeed it is)

```
public function updatedPickeddatetime($value)
{
    $rules = $this->rules();

    $rules['pickeddatetime'][] = new TimeSlotEmployeeRule($this->employee_id);
    $this->validateOnly('pickeddatetime', $rules);
}
```

In the `TimeSlotEmployeeRule` the `passes` method returns `false` (for testing purposes).

I placed some strategic `dd`s inside the `validateOnly` method, and i can see that the `ValidationException` is thrown and the `ErrorBag` contains the expected message.

Yet, the `@error` directive (for the `p` element) isn't triggered and the element is not shown.

## Update 2: solved!

Apparently, the problem was related, but laying somewhere else: the `@error` directive works fine, but I noticed that in the DOM the `p` was set as `display:none`. This, I think, is related to the fact that the input doesn't get its `is-invalid` class, and thus the `invalid-feedback` gets hidden.

I therefore changed it to `<p class="invalid-feedback d-block">` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48401860/1785967)) and it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the `wire:ignore` on the parent div makes Livewire ignore any updates to that part of the DOM. It will never change anything inside of it.

So, to make the paragraph show, simply move the `wire:ignore` down on the input itself.

```html
<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="pickeddatetime" class="form-label">Date and time</label>
    <input id="pickeddatetime" wire:ignore.self class="form-control @error('pickeddatetime') is-invalid @enderror"
           type="datetime-local" name="pickeddatetime" placeholder="Pick a date and time"
           value="{{ old('pickeddatetime') }}" wire:model.debounce.500ms="pickeddatetime">
    @error('pickeddatetime')
    <p class="invalid-feedback">{{ $errors->first('pickeddatetime') }}</p>
    @enderror
</div>
```

You will still need `wire:ignore` or `wire:ignore.self` on the input, as the Flatpickr library will modify and maintain state of the actual input.

This only solves half of your issue though, as you will still not get the class `is-invalid` applied when the validation for that property fails. To achieve this, either put the class on a wrapper, and then apply CSS in such a way that it'll be put on the input, or else you would need some sort of listener or change-event on the Flatpickr instance, and then check if the validation failed before applying or removing the class on the input, meaning that you apply it with JavaScript.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I tried on a simple numeric input (to see if the problem is related to flatpickr or not): wherever I put `wire:ignore` or `wire:ignore.self` (`div` or `input` doesn't matter) the `error` directives are not triggered.

Comment: Well, let's see your code then. Could it be that you haven't added `@livewireScripts`, or that you have another `wire:ignore`?

Comment: I updated my question with further information. I agree with you that what you suggested should work, yet I can't understand why it doesn't.

Comment: I finally worked it out and updated my solution for sake of completeness. Your suggestion to my original question (move the `wire:ignore` in the `input`) was indeed the correct one to fix the problem, so have it accepted!

Comment: Ah, happy to hear you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

To work around this, you can use a JavaScript event that will manually emit an event to Livewire when your datepicker's value changes.

```
<div class="mb-3" wire:ignore>
    <label for="pickeddatetime" class="form-label">Date and time</label>
    <input id="pickeddatetime" class="form-control @error('pickeddatetime') is-invalid @enderror"
           type="text" placeholder="Pick a date and time"
           value="{{ old('pickeddatetime') }}">
    @error('pickeddatetime')
    <p class="invalid-feedback">{{ $errors->first('pickeddatetime') }}</p>
    @enderror
</div>

<script>
    flatpickr("#pickeddatetime", {
        enableTime: true,
        dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i", // or your preferred date format
        onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
            @this.set('pickeddatetime', dateStr);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting your point, but the data _is_ send back and forth with the backend. My problem is that the validation, when fails, doesn't trigger the @error directives